# Defining and calling a method

Tags: c#

I am new to OOP. Hope someone clarify my doubt.

If I want to call a method like

```
int number = numberMethod();
```

What should be the method definition??

```
public void numberMethod(out int num)
{
    num = 3;
}
```

or

```
public int numberMethod()
{
    int num = 3;
    return num;
}
```

or both definition are same??

Comment: The second is usually the prefered method. `out` is usually used when you want to both assign a value back _and_ return a value as a result. For example, if you wanted to return a `true` or `false` on successful parse as with [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx). If you aren't doing that, then just use the `return` value rather than an `out`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second one,

Because you are calling method as below that means you are calling method that retuns value

```
int number = numberMethod();
```

method

```
public int numberMethod()
{
    int num = 3;
    return num;
}
```

if you want to user first one than you need to call it like

```
int number ;
numberMethod(out number);
```

because you are having void return value and specifying out in param

method

```
public void numberMethod(out int num)
{
    num = 3;
}
```

Comment: Thaank you Pranay, What is my method has 2 input parameter and one output parameter like:

public void getAgentsOnReserveCount(DateTime sd, int t, out int x)
{

}

then calling the method like:

lblAgentsOnReserve.Text = getAgentsOnReserveCount(d1,4).ToString();

gives you an error on "no overload method".

Comment: @Vinnie - to avoid error you need to specify out there that means you code will be "int a=4; lblAgentsOnReserve.Text = getAgentsOnReserveCount(d1,out a).ToString();" - read about out keyword on msdn will give you idea how and when to use it.

Answer (score 4):

No, they're not the same. You've got to use the second form, not the first.

If you try to use the return value of the method - which is what you're doing here:

```
int number = numberMethod();
```

then the method has to have an appropriate return type - one that's implicitly convertible to `int`. You can't call a `void` method like that, and C# doesn't implicitly treat "method with `out` parameter and `void` return type" as "method with a return type matching the `out` parameter type".

It's *very, very* rarely a good idea to include an `out` parameter in a method with a `void` return type. (In fact, it's relatively rarely a good idea to use `out` parameters at all, IMO. They normally indicate that a single method is trying to do too much.)

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not the same method, its very much clear from the signature of the message,

```
public int numberMethod()  // return as integer
{
    int num = 3;
    return num;
}
```

is the correct method to be used for what your need is.

The second method

```
public void numberMethod(out int num)
{
    num = 3;
}
```

can be used too but **`You need to change the way it is invoked`**

it can be used like

```
int num;
numberMethod(out num);
```

both the method will end having same effect, i.e. `num` will have the value `3`.

---

`out` parameter in a method is only preferred when, you need to have more then one return value from the `method/function`.